# Omit a condition in SQL dynamically

Tags: sql, gridview, case

[image]I am developing a website with Asp.net. I have a problem in the following code!
I want to use the DataSqlSource and a attached it to Gridview. I also have a drop down list for categorizing in that page. What i want is, to categorize the Gridview by drop down list. In this case in one condition, a condition must be omitted from the query(Step3_AddArticleType.Status = @Status). For example when the drop down list value is 'All', the mentioned condition must not be counting. 
Can any body help me?

I don't know the structure of using that. Here is the code in my DataSqlSource:

```
SELECT  Step3_AddArticleType.ArticleType, Step3_AddArticleType.JournalName, Step5_AddTitle.FullTitle, Step3_AddArticleType.Status, Step3_AddArticleType.ArticleNum, 
Step5_AddTitle.ArticleID, Step3_AddArticleType.ID, Step3_AddArticleType.Date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Step3_AddArticleType.Date, 103) AS SubmissionDate

FROM Step3_AddArticleType 
INNER JOIN Step5_AddTitle ON Step3_AddArticleType.ArticleID = Step5_AddTitle.ArticleID    
WHERE        (Step3_AddArticleType.CheckFinish = '0') 
AND (Step3_AddArticleType.JournalName = @JournalName) 
CASE 
WHEN @Status<>'All' THEN   
AND (Step3_AddArticleType.Status = @Status)    
END
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition should be like below. Put `OR` between checking for all and a specific value:

```
WHERE (Step3_AddArticleType.CheckFinish = '0') AND (Step3_AddArticleType.JournalName = @JournalName)
AND (@Status = 'All' OR Step3_AddArticleType.Status = @Status)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i want is when a user select 'All' from the drop down list the Step3_AddArticleType.Status = @Status condition omit, and when he select other items this condition stay. Unfortunately it doesn't work when i select all!

Comment: This is why you need `OR`. If the user selects "All", the first part is true and hence the whole is true. It is like omitting the second part. Have you tried that?

Comment: There is no 'All' status in the database but, it will be passed to queries by a drop down list as i mentioned before!
So we need Status = @Status for 'All' status. By this way the datasql source distinguish that the status will be come from drop down list.

Comment: @Status is fill with dropdownlist!
The drop down list have All statuses, which exist in data base except 'All' status. So it will be easy to categorize others. but  the one which is not in data base is my problem!

Comment: Ok, but you have to pass something in @Status parameter in the case the user selected all. What is it?

Comment: It is 'All'. I put that in drop down list. and it doesn't exist in DB's column.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have filter to show all statuses, So that i added this item("All") to my drop down list. It can be what ever you like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43314/discussion-between-szymon-and-saeed-talaee)